# Error connecting Chatgpt API to Discord Server

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm trying to use the ChatGPT Api and connect to a discord bot but I am getting this error.  Can anyone show me how to fix this?

**Error**

> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use
> import instead This file is being treated as an ES module because it
> has a '.js' file extension and
> 'C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\gpt\package.json' contains "type":
> "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the
> '.cjs' file extension.

**Full Code**

```
import Discord from 'discord.js';
import { ChatGPTAPI } from 'chatgpt';
import readline from 'readline';

const apiKey = 'hidden';
const api = new ChatGPTAPI({ apiKey });
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
  

let conversationId;
let parentMessageId;

async function sendMessage(message, channel) {
  let res = await api.sendMessage(message, {
    conversationId: conversationId,
    parentMessageId: parentMessageId
  });

  conversationId = res.conversationId;
  parentMessageId = res.id;

  console.log('\nBot:', res.text, '\n');

  if (channel) {
    await channel.send(res.text);
  }
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === 'quit') {
    process.exit();
  }

  await sendMessage(message.content, message.channel);
});

async function main() {
  await sendMessage('Hello World!');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  function askQuestion() {
    rl.question('\nYou: ', async (question) => {
      if (question === 'quit') {
        rl.close();
        process.exit();
      }

      await sendMessage(question);
      askQuestion();
    });
  }

  askQuestion();
}

client.login('hidden');
main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you cannot use `require` in an ES module, and you should use `import` instead. However, in your code, you are using both `require` and `import` statements.

It is a simple fix by replacing `require` with `import`
Example:

```
import Discord, { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';
```

Full Code:

```
import Discord, { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';
import { ChatGPTAPI } from 'chatgpt';
import readline from 'readline';

const apiKey = 'hidden';
const api = new ChatGPTAPI({ apiKey });


const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
  

let conversationId;
let parentMessageId;

async function sendMessage(message, channel) {
  let res = await api.sendMessage(message, {
    conversationId: conversationId,
    parentMessageId: parentMessageId
  });

  conversationId = res.conversationId;
  parentMessageId = res.id;

  console.log('\nBot:', res.text, '\n');

  if (channel) {
    await channel.send(res.text);
  }
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === 'quit') {
    process.exit();
  }

  await sendMessage(message.content, message.channel);
});

async function main() {
  await sendMessage('Hello World!');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  function askQuestion() {
    rl.question('\nYou: ', async (question) => {
      if (question === 'quit') {
        rl.close();
        process.exit();
      }

      await sendMessage(question);
      askQuestion();
    });
  }

  askQuestion();
}

client.login('hidden');
main();
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error.  import Discord, { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';
                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Intents' not found. The requested module 'discord.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
import pkg from 'discord.js';
const { Client, Intents } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)

Node.js v19.6.0

Comment: What discordJS version are you using?